# Detect elements' visibility after adding Display:none using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have four divs in a main container.

```
<div id="boxes">
    <div class="inner-box"></div>
    <div class="inner-box"></div>
    <div class="inner-box"></div>
    <div class="inner-box"></div>
</div>
```

After a javascript click event, `display: none` is added to them to hide. So I want to do something when no elements are visible.

```
if ($('#boxes').children(':visible').length == 0)
```

The above code does not seem to be working because it counts the number of visible elements before the click event (even if all the classes have `display: none it gives` the count 4).

I'm using `change();` function for select to toggle the display property.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wnzavyom/1/

Comment: So run your nothing-visible-code after your change?

Comment: How are you hiding the element on click? Is it using `hide()`, or via an animation?

Comment: Have you tried using jquery's `:hidden` filter instead?

Comment: Your code works fine, but how are you hiding them? http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/rt7xvs29/ Please show the rest of the code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8kujk0rs/1/ if works great for me.

Comment: how are you making them invisible.... are you display/visibility/height

Comment: Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/wnzavyom/

Comment: inside the `change()` function call another function and have this if condition over there to check so that when ever you change the `display` property for any `inner-box` the visibilty gets checked and you can do what u want,

Comment: But I agree with @TrueBlueAussie that you code should also work. Can you add this line after the click: `console.log($('#boxes > ,inner-box:visible'));` and check what it returns in the dev tools?

Comment: GUYS! check this out and see what happens http://jsfiddle.net/wnzavyom/1/
@RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is because your boxes are being hidden using `fadeOut()` which runs asynchronously. This means that when you check the number of `:visible` elements the animation has not yet finished, so they are still technically visible.

To achieve what you need you should run your code in the callback of the `fadeOut()` method. Try this:

```
$('#filter select').change(function () {
     $('.inner-box').fadeOut(function() {
         if ($('#boxes').children(':visible').length == 0) {
             alert('all boxes hidden');
         }
     });
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wnzavyom/2/)

Comment: yes, you are right. I'm really just beginner when it comes to Javascript. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 2):

Basically every time you process the onclick event you have to then check each item to see if it exhibits the css setting `display: none`

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w6831v6t/))

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('.inner-box').on("click",function(){
    $(this).css("display","none");
    var visible = false;
    $('.inner-box',$(this).parent()).each(function(){
        if($(this).css("display") !== "none") visible = true;
    });
    if(!visible) alert("All gone");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<select id="showhide">
    <option>hide</option>
    <option>show</option>
</select>
<div id="boxes">
 <div class="inner-box">one</div>
 <div class="inner-box">two</div>
 <div class="inner-box">three</div>
 <div class="inner-box">four</div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
$('.inner-box').hide();
$('#showhide').on('change',function(){
    $('.inner-box').toggle();
    alert($('#boxes').children(':visible').length);
});
alert($('#boxes').children(':visible').length);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bk22wtse/1/)**

Comment: @ Rory McCrossan I forgot to include `jquery`